# How to check which items are not issued in a specific Date Range in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've two tables `Products` and `Products Issued`

I want to check which items are not issued in a specific date range, or having a count of 0 in a date range. I've written the following query but it is not showing any result

```
SELECT p.ProductName, COUNT(i.Id) AS TotalIssued FROM Products p
LEFT JOIN ProductIssue i ON i.ProductId = p.Id
WHERE i.IssueDate between '2019-01-01' AND '2019-12-25'
GROUP BY i.ProductId, p.ProductName
having COUNT(i.Id) = 0
```

Comment: `having COUNT(i.Id) = 0` means no matching records....I think in your case this is unnecessary

Comment: are you suggesting to remove this `having` case?

Comment: Yes...due to this condition your not getting the records which are fall under certain dates

Comment: @JaydipJadhav i think this will not show records with 0 values

Comment: yes @AgentSmith is right, it is not showing records with rows with 0 if i remove `having clause`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of issues:

1. you need to move the `i.IssueDate between '2019-01-01' AND '2019-12-25'` condition into the `ON` clause of the `LEFT JOIN`, otherwise you convert it into an `INNER JOIN`;
2. You can't group on `i.ProductId` as it will be `NULL` when the product was not issued in the date range, so you need to use `p.Id` instead.

This should work:

```
SELECT p.ProductName, COUNT(i.Id) AS TotalIssued 
FROM Products p
LEFT JOIN ProductIssue i ON i.ProductId = p.Id AND i.IssueDate between '2019-01-01' AND '2019-12-25'
GROUP BY p.Id, p.ProductName
HAVING COUNT(i.Id) = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be done without any aggregation function:

```
SELECT p.ProductName
FROM Products p
LEFT JOIN ProductIssue i 
  ON i.ProductId = p.Id
  AND i.IssueDate BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-12-25'
WHERE i.Id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try by this

SELECT p.ProductName
FROM Products p
LEFT JOIN ProductIssue i ON i.ProductId = p.Id AND cast(i.IssueDate as date) BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-12-25'
WHERE i.Id IS NULL